# In Typescript, Why do I need to redefine the interface and its class after defining the interface with implements

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Filter {
  rowAddRow: (treeData:Tree[],id:string,filterType:FilterType) =>Tree[]
}

class FilterAction implements Filter {
  // I need to redeclare here, if not, just like id, it type is any
  rowAddRow(treeData:Tree[], id, filterType):Tree[] { 
      // todo sth
  }
}

class Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.actions = new FilterAction()
  }

  // I also need to define the function interface again here
  private actions: {
    rowAddRow: (treeData:Tree[],id:string,filterType:FilterType) =>Tree[]
  }

  handleAdd() {
    this.actions.rowAddRow()
  }
}
```

in my opinion:
Since the interface of the function `rowAddRow` is defined in `FilterAction`, it should automatically have this method when used in its instance, and the method has the previously specified interface type and does not need to be redefined

So, Why do I need to redefine the interface and its class after defining the interface with implements

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to redefine the interface and its class after defining the interface with implements

Reasons are covered here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207

So it is made the responsibility of the developer to add the annotations they need.

## Why its not enough of a reason

Because all features start at `-100` : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx